# Executing SQL Query and then using OUTFILE to generate a dynamic file name

Tags: mysql

This is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
SELECT start_time,calling_nr FROM cdr
WHERE ccs_list LIKE '%Sample Incomplete%'
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\cciv-'DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i'),'.txt\'');
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function called CONCAT(), which will give you the output that you're looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
INTO OUTFILE CONCAT('C:\\cciv-', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i'), '.txt')
```

should work for you